# Pin documents to home page

Tags: 2013, web-part

Is there an out of the box web part that might allow one to "pin" documents from one or more libraries?

My use case is I'd like a webpart on the homepage to show documents pinned from various different libraries, rather than just an MRU list.

Thought I'd ask before spending a bunch of time on this.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box the simplest solution would be a links list.  Just add links for the items to the list and then add a view of the list to the home page.